# Dispalying a pdf/doc file on a webpage

Tags: javascript, client-server, html

how to display pdf file or doc file on a webpage which is getting from the remote location.
    For example- from server to client

```
<!DOCTYPE html> //specifying the html version
<html> //a html file will show on to the remote browser
<head>// head element of an html
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
 <script>
    function addMoreInputType() //custom function when a button is clicked
    { // opening of a function
    var ip=document.getElementById("p1"); // id of a <p>tag
    var cele=document.createElement("embed");//creating a new html element
    cele.setAttribute("src","1.pdf"); //setting an attribute named src and 1.pdf is the pdf file on the server which i wanted to show on the client browser
    cele.setAttribute("width","600px"); //setting an attribute named width to diplay
    cele.setAttribute("height","500px");//setting an attribute named height
    cele.setAttribute("alt","pdf");
             cele.setAttribute("pluginspace","http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2 .html");// that is the plugin
    cele.setAttribute("internalinstanceid","14");// that is setting the attribute for the new html element

    ip.appendChild(cele);// finally appending it to p tag child
    } //closing of a function
 </script> // ending of the script tag
</head> //end of the head tag
<body> // the content to be displayed on the client browser
  <input type="button" value=" clickme " onclick="addMoreInputType()">Button click// a button which on clicking will invoke the addM....() so that they will request to server to give the pdf file and show onto browser's webpage area
  <p id="p1"></p> // p tag having id p1

</body>//end of body of html
</html>//end of html file
```

Comment: You just need the right libraries to read their content. There after you can display it. For pdf, there is itext library.

Comment: can you provide me the updated solution

Comment: with the ajax code coz i m using ajax

Answer (score 0):

check the path of your Pdf file.

if you are able to access it from normal browser then you should be able to display it on web page.

Also set type

cele.setAttribute("type","application/pdf");